# Intellij Ultimate 2019.3.3 How to run SQL from file

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a file called `my_table.tbl` which has DDL SQL, I opened the file in Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2019.3.3, but it does not understand that this is a file with SQL statement and I cannot execute anything!

Note that changing the file extension (to .sql ?) is not an option. I just want to run pieces sql from any of my files *.TBL fles, just like I can do so in SQL Developer and many other tools. How do I do this in IntelliJ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associate `*.tbl` with SQL files in File | Settings | Editor | File Types:

[image: File types]

Comment: That is fine, but I still do not see the SQL execution controls (see my original screenshot) nor a way to associate it with any of my active db connection, even if the file is recognized as containing sql.

Comment: @HristoStoyanov [Works fine here](https://i.imgur.com/6y5RUyr.png). Do you have Execute option in the file context menu? Did you install any third party plug-ins that may handle SQL files instead of the bundled database support?

Comment: @HristoStoyanov your screenshot shows that file has Text file type icon, not SQL type icon, see [this screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/6y5RUyr.png) with the proper file type association. Notice that the file icon on the editor tab is different.

Comment: argh .. figured it out! The SQL toolbar shows only after you run EXECUTE from the context menu (on whatever part of the file) once, and then stays there!